# External Table on file without terninator

Tags: sql, oracle, external-tables

let's suppose I have a file like this:

```
101010AAAABBB
```

where I don't have a symbol for separating the different fields and I want to load it into an external table
In the definition of my external table I would usually put

```
access parameters (records delimited by newline
fields terminated by ";"
```

if I had

```
101010;AAAA;BBB
```

But in my case, how can I write the syntax for loading every field in positional way?

Oracle version 10g

Thanks!
Mark

Answer (score 1):

As you said - **positional**.

Sample `test.txt` file contents:

```
101010AAAABBB
555555CCCCDDD
```

External table:

```
SQL> create table tpos
  2    (col1 char(6),
  3     col2 char(4),
  4     col3 char(3)
  5    )
  6  organization external
  7    (type oracle_loader
  8     default directory ext_dir
  9     access parameters (records delimited by newline
 10                        fields ldrtrim
 11                       (col1 (1:6),
 12                        col2 (7:10),
 13                        col3 (11:13)
 14                       ))
 15     location ('test.txt'))
 16     reject limit unlimited;

Table created.

SQL> select * From tpos;

COL1   COL2 COL
------ ---- ---
101010 AAAA BBB
555555 CCCC DDD

SQL>
```